# What am I doing wrong as I create unique directory and files, while validating directory and files names are unique using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, unique, versioning, directory-structure

I wrote this code to do the following:

- Create a directory structure for (Must check and create unique directory)

  Each Litter Location

  Each Sire Type

  Each Sire Name

  Each Dam Name

  Each Dam Type + S_D + Litter Number
- Create File Name to include (Must check and create unique file)

  Sire Type

  Sire Name

  Dam Name

  Dam Name

  Litter Number

Problem: Error checking is not working as expected continuously.

```
function Create-PigLitters
{
       param ([string[]]$SireType = @('Hereford','Mangalista','Yorkshire', 'Cross'),
              [string]$SireName,
              [int]$LitterNumber,
              [string]$DamName,
              [string]$LitterLocation,
        [string[]]$DamType = @('Hereford','Mangalista','Yorkshire', 'Cross')),

       #Create Directory

    $PigletProject = $LitterLocation + "\" + $SireType + "\" + "$SireName" + "_" + $DamName+ "\" + $DamType + "_S_D"  + $LitterNumber

       if (!(Test-Path -Path $PigletProject))
              {
              New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "$PigletProject"
       }
    else
    {
        [int]$LitterNumber++
        $PigletProject = $LitterLocation + "\" + $SireType + "\" + "$SireName" + "_" + $DamName + "\" + $DamType + "_S_D"  + $LitterNumber
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "$PigletProject" -Force
    }


    #Create File
    $FileName = $SireType + "_" + $SireName + "_" + $DamName + "_" + $DamType + "_S_D" + $LitterNumber + ".txt"
       if (!(Test-Path -Path "$PigletProject\$FileName"))
       {
              New-Item -ItemType "file" -Path "$PigletProject\$FileName"
       }
    else 
    {
            [int]$LitterNumber++
            $FileName = $SireType + "_" + $SireName + "_" + $DamName + "_" + $DamType + "_S_D" + $LitterNumber + ".txt"
            New-Item -ItemType "file" -Path "$PigletProject\$FileName" -Force
    }
}
```

What am I doing incorrectly to get consistent results and how do I fix it?

Comment: "Error checking is not working as expected continuously" - what is expected?

Comment: are you wanting to create a directory TREE or just ONE directory with that really long name? does that also apply to the file name?

Comment: `if-else` is not enough to create unique items. consider using the `do-while` statement. `do { $PigletProject = ... } while (Test-Path -Path $PigletProject); New-Item $PigletProject -ItemType ...`